# pickle functions and modules in python3

Tags: python, function, module, python-3.4, pickle

I would like to save a dictionary containing modules, functions, classes and the like. When trying to pickle this, I get the error:

```
Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed
```

An example of my dictionary would be:

```
{
  'json': <module 'json' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py'>
  'foo':  <function foo at 0x7fd8a2a8bbf8>
  'bar':  "I'm a string!"
}
```

Currently I just do:

```
pickle.dump(data, open(path, "wb"))
```

What should I change?

Comment: You can't pickle a module. You could instead pickle an identifer that can be used to import the module later

Comment: What identifier would I use? How would I break them down, and reconstruct them?

Comment: See if this helps: [Alternatives to pickling a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336908/python-alternatives-to-pickling-a-module)

Comment: Modules are compiled and saved as byte-code in `.pyc` files, and this is a similar type of format to pickle - although less advanced.  So you could use that instead, but they are not meant as transportable objects, so why not just bundle the module source files with the pickle as a zip or tar file?  Or maybe create a distribution with them using `distutils`?